# Stripe subscription free trial with no card

Tags: python, stripe-payments, stripes

I am trying to implement Stripe subscription with Stripe Checkout. All plans of my application have 14 days free trial. I can implement free trial by setting `trial_end` in `create checkout session` API, but it required Card information by default. I need to implement Free trial with No Card. Customer will attach card information after trial period end. How can I do this?

Comment: you need to keep track of it ... once the trial is up, then use stripe to charge them next time they login or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Stripe Checkout requires payment information to be provided at creation time for trialing subscriptions. If you want to be able to not collect payment information for trialing subscriptions you'll have to make the request to create the Subscription yourself through the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create) and then bring the customer back to your site when the trial is over to provide payment details.